# How to convert a String containing name-value pairs into an associate array or some other structure which supports name-value pairs?

Tags: php, json, associative-array, stdclass

I have a string that looks like this:

```
{"red":216.77,"blue":0.669,"green":0.545,"alpha":1}
```

I want to save it in either an array like this:

```
array(
  "red" => 216.77,
  "blue" => 0.669,
  green" => 0.545,
  "alpha" => 1
)
```

or some other structure (like stdclass) containing name-value pairs, so that I can traverse it and retrieve values by names.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

`$object = json_decode("JSON response goes here")`

`$object->property`